# Relationship between univariate and multivariate normal distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution, univariate

I have a portfolio consisting of N assets with known average historical returns ($r_1$, $r_2$, ...$r_N$) and a known set of weights ($a_1$, $a_2$, ...$a_N$) subject to $\sum_{i=1}^N a_i$ = 1

I am currently running a Monte-Carlo simulation of this portfolio by first aggregating the individual securities to arrive at the portfolio mean and variance

$\mu_p$ = $\sum_{i=1}^N a_i\times r_i$ and

$\sigma_p^2$ = $\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N a_i a_jCov(r_i, r_j)$

I then draw 10000 random samples over a number of periods T from the univariate normal distribution with mean $\mu_p$ and variance $\sigma_p^2$ to produce projections of future portfolio values.

For the purposes of my analysis, however, I'd need to simulate individual assets directly and only then aggregate them to a portfolio using the set of weights I have. So what I tried to do was to draw from a multivariate normal distribution characterised by a vector of means equivalent to ($r_1$, $r_2$, ...$r_N$) and a covariance matrix in line with the historical covariance between my assets (which is anyway used to come up with the portfolio covariance $\sigma_p^2$

I was expecting to get equivalent results between the two methodologies (drawing from the univariate with aggregated portfolio moments and drawing from the multivariate with per-asset first and second moments and only then combining it in a portfolio), but it seems like the multivariate random samples always have a slightly lower median return than the univariate random samples.

What am I missing here? Is there an additional adjustment needed to be made to the multivariate case? Any ideas are appreciated